# Adobe XD unable to lunch the product automatically please quit & launch manually. (Error code 111)

Tags: adobe

When I install the XD it showed "installation complete...unable to lunch the product automatically please quit & launch manually. (Error code 111)"

last month I installed it successfully and then I formatted my  PC and upgraded my Windows 10 to pro then the problem is here.
even when I open my files to open it manually I can't find anything?
WHAT TO DO!?

Answer (score 0):

The application has been installed successfully, but it is unable to open the program automatically after installation.
So, go to start, look for the installed app, and open it. It should work well!